# Is there a graph paper like drawing software?

Tags: charts, drawing

I have a college assignment, where I have to draw diagrams of voronoi, delaunay, minimum spanning tree etc for the college. I want to do that in computer. I searched in google with no luck. Is there any good graph drawing software you are aware of?

Answer (score 9):

There is [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  It can be tedious at times, but it's very flexible.

Answer (score 5):

For simple "hand drawn" stuff, I use Inkscape for everything.

http://www.inkscape.org

Answer (score 4):

This works fine as it is online and you can save your results
http://www.garrettbartley.com/graphpaper.html

The save button creates a png image of what you've done.  Once you leave the page, it doesn't preserve the working detail, so you could not return to the page and continue where you left off.

Answer (score 2):

Graph Paper Printer has always worked well for me...

http://download.cnet.com/Graph-Paper-Printer/3000-2064_4-10037453.html